# Few VM instances in a backend service are unhealthy while configuring HTTPS load balancer on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

As part of load balancer creation using Unmanaged instance groups, we created 4 unmanaged instance groups each of them containing a single VM.

Out of the 4 VMs , 2 VMs are in the same zone europe-west1-c and are healthy and the other 2 VMs are in europe-west1-b and d zones and are unhealthy.

We have kept TCP and port 80 in the health check for the backend service. we are using a single backend service for all the 4 VMs.

Please suggest us how do we troubleshoot these unhealthy instances and fix this so that traffic can be spread across all 4 vm's.

Comment: Of course, I assume that the firewall rule are open and the 2 unhealthy VM correctly answer when you test them on the port 80?

Comment: Are your "unhealthy" instances in west1-b are working as expected and listening on port 80 ? Are you sure that the configuration is correct ?

Comment: yes issue got resolved after recreating vm as it is not listening on port 80 earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes issue got resolved after recreating vm as it is not listening on port 80 earlier